# How to display first name, last name and salary of all subordinates from HR. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to display first name, last name and salary of all subordinates from HR on Oracle?

I have:

```
SELECT J.JOB_TITLE, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.SALARY, (SELECT SUM(EMPLOYEES.SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES)
FROM JOBS J LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON J.JOB_ID = E.JOB_ID 
GROUP BY J.JOB_TITLE, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.SALARY
ORDER BY E.SALARY DESC;
```

But it shows the total salary:

```
SELECT SUM(EMPLOYEES.SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES
```

Schema:
[image]

Thx.

Comment: Slaves do not need salary.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. What is a "slave" in this context? And why are you involving the job tablee if you don't need anything to do with the jobs? And what is HR? A sample schema?

Comment: @lad2025 I fixed this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I got this right, you want your last column to be the total salary of all the subordinate employees, both direct and indirect.  If so, you can use a `connect by` clause in the subquery to get that information.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT j.job_title,
       e.first_name.
       e.last_name,
       e.salary,
       (
          SELECT SUM(s.salary)
            FROM employees s
           START WITH s.manager_id = e.employee_id,
         CONNECT BY PRIOR s.employee_id = s.manager_id
       ) AS total_subordinate_salary
  FROM jobs j 
  LEFT JOIN employees e
    ON j.job_id = e.job_id
 GROUP BY j.job_title, e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.salary
 ORDER BY e.salary DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT 
  J.JOB_TITLE, 
  E.FIRST_NAME, 
  E.LAST_NAME, 
  E.SALARY, 
  (SELECT SUM(EMPLOYEES.SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES where manager_id = e.employee_id) 
FROM 
  JOBS J LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON J.JOB_ID = E.JOB_ID 
GROUP BY 
  J.JOB_TITLE, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.SALARY
ORDER BY 
  E.SALARY DESC;
```

let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: It works, but it works only for direct subordinates, and it is necessary for indirect (including all dependent).

Comment: Can you give me an example of indirect ?

Comment: It works for (example: president = managers + vice presdents), but need (president = managers + vice presdents, where managers = representative + programmers, and vice presidents = managers etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the SUM function if you want each employees salary? Can you be a bit more descriptive about what you are actually trying to obtain and what is not being obtained from your provided query?

My guess is you want just the salaries of HR Employees so you need to add a where clause. You need to check your data and see what the actual department name is. is it "HR" "Human Resources" etc. 
i.e.

```
WHERE E.DEPARTMENT_ID = 'HR'
```

So try this :

```
SELECT J.JOB_TITLE, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.SALARY, (SELECT SUM(EMPLOYEES.SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES)
FROM JOBS J LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES E ON J.JOB_ID = E.JOB_ID 
WHERE E.DEPARTMENT_ID = 'HR'  
GROUP BY J.JOB_TITLE, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, E.SALARY
ORDER BY E.SALARY DESC;
```

Comment: I cant add comments and I was adding my best guess at an answer but thank you for the downvote at this rate I will never be able to add a comment...

Comment: Just be patient, or make sure you add an actual answer.  Now that you've edited your answer, there is no longer a problem. :)